# W/art: Native thread exiting without having called DetachCurrentThread VlcObject

Tags: android, libvlc

I'm getting this warning in my application using lib Vlc for android.

> W/art: Native thread exiting without having called DetachCurrentThread (maybe it's going to use a pthread_key_create destructor?): Thread[56,tid=6197,Native,Thread*=0xba2fe820,peer=0x13576100,"VlcObject"]

Is it a problem?

Comment: I see this same warning with Epson's EPos2 printer SDK on Android. Just putting that here for future readers - this is the post that google led me to.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier any references for this issue with epson printer? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @Ashwini sorry I never got any further with that - we ended up ignoring it and as far as I know it is in production without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This warning was fixed in [MobileVLCKit](https://cocoapods.org/pods/MobileVLCKit) version 3+

Comment: Unfortunately that iOS and irrelevant.